# Manipulate HTML in React/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to source a CMS (Wordpress) in React, everything works as expected, but i'm now at the point that i need to show the post content.
The posts are (mostly) returned in this format:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some more text</p>
<figure class=...">
   <ul class="...">
     <li class="...">
       <figure>
         <a href="..">
           <img src="">
         </a>
       </figure>
     </li>
     ...
    <li class="...">
       <figure>
         <a href="..">
           <img src="">
         </a>
       </figure>
    </li>
   </ul>
</figure>
<p>More text</p>
<figure>....</figure>
<p>And so on</p>
```

all this html get its style from wordpress and the "figure" parts are masonry gallery with lightbox (working inside wordpress)
my idea was to traverse this block of html in javascript and rebuild the output (every top html should populate an array of object) and in the meantime rebuild the galleries to make them compatible with react
something like:

```
[{type:'p', content:'Some text'}, {type:'gallery' content:['img_1_url', 'img_2_url', ...]}, ... ]
```

are there some ready to use tools to make something like that? or should i go with regex?

Comment: What does "source a CMS" mean here?

Comment: What do you mean by "source a CMS in react"? If you want to render content from your cms with react you should use an API to fetch the data from your server and use just react to render it. There are frameworks like gatsby or next.js dedicated to do just that. I don't think it's a good idea to parse some html to somehow transform it into a format that can be rendered with react.

Comment: my site is already in Next, i simply don't want to render the html that comes from the cms as is (wordpress save the 'content' already with styles and other markup so it contains styles and things that works on wordpress specific javascript like the galleries and lightbox) thats why (once i got my data, and i can get it easily) i need to reformat the "content" to reflect the work (especially galleries). I can't of course rewrite the content on the CMS since there already over thousand articles and people will need to continue writing the way they already do